# LINQ sum not performed when values are identical

Tags: c#, linq

I need to `sum` elements of same type starting from 2 LINQ queries.

Below is my code:

```
        var query1 = from d in _contextProvider.Context.Documents
                     where d.TransportId == transportId
                     group d by d.Type
                     into dg
                     select new { DocumentType = dg.Key.ToString(), DocumentCount = dg.Count() };

        var query2 = from n in _contextProvider.Context.NotificationDocuments
                     where n.TransportId == transportId
                     group n by n.TransportId
                     into nd
                     select new { DocumentType = "Notification", DocumentCount = nd.Count() };

        var query_collapsed = query1.Union(query2)
                    .GroupBy(p => new { DocumentType = p.DocumentType })
                    .Select(g => new DocumentCounters() { DocumentType = g.Key.DocumentType, DocumentCount = g.Sum(p => p.DocumentCount) });
```

Example: below let's analyse values for `DocumentType` equals to `Notification`.

Values of query1:

[image]

Values of query2:

[image]

The collapsed query :

[image]

That's correct: 1 + 2 = 3

**The problem**: I noticed that whenever the count for `Notification` in query1 is equals to the count for `Notification` in query2, then the sum is not performed.

Example:

2 + 2 = 2

or

3 + 3 = 3

Any ideas ?

Comment: `Union` will only keep distinct items.

Comment: I think if you want to keep duplicate entries in the resulting collection you need to use `Concat` not `Union`.

Comment: @JurgenCamilleri was right, use `Concat` instead of `Union`

Comment: That's correct. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ `Union` will remove duplicate entries. If you want to merge the two sequences you can use `Concat` like so:

```
var query_collapsed = query1.Concat(query2)
                .GroupBy(p => new { DocumentType = p.DocumentType })
                .Select(g => new DocumentCounters() { DocumentType = g.Key.DocumentType, DocumentCount = g.Sum(p => p.DocumentCount) });
```